# how to join tables on cases where none of function(a) in b

Tags: sql, monetdb, monetdblite

Say in MonetDB (specifically, the embedded version from the "MonetDBLite" R package) I have a table "events" containing entity ID codes and event start and end dates, of the format:

```
| id  | start_date  | end_date   |
| 1   | 2010-01-01  | 2010-03-30 |
| 1   | 2010-04-01  | 2010-06-30 |
| 2   | 2018-04-01  | 2018-06-30 |
| ... | ...         | ...        |
```

The table is approximately 80 million rows of events, attributable to approximately 2.5 million unique entities (ID values).  The dates appear to align nicely with calendar quarters, but I haven't thoroughly checked them so assume they can be arbitrary.  However, I have at least sense-checked them for end_date > start_date.

I want to produce a table "nonevent_qtrs" listing calendar quarters where an ID has *no* event recorded, *e.g.*:

```
| id  | last_doq   |
| 1   | 2010-09-30 |
| 1   | 2010-12-31 |
| ... | ...        |
| 1   | 2018-06-30 |
| 2   | 2010-03-30 |
| ... | ...        |
```

(doq = day of quarter)

If the extent of an event spans any days of the quarter (including the first and last dates), then I wish for it to count as having occurred in that quarter.

To help with this, I have produced a "calendar table"; a table of quarters "qtrs", covering the entire span of dates present in "events", and of the format:

```
| first_doq  | last_doq   |
| 2010-01-01 | 2010-03-30 |
| 2010-04-01 | 2010-06-30 |
| ...        | ...        |
```

And tried using a non-equi merge like so:

```
create table nonevents
as select
    id,
    last_doq
from
    events
    full outer join
    qtrs
on
    start_date > last_doq or
    end_date < first_doq
group by
    id,
    last_doq
```

But this is a) terribly inefficient and b) certainly wrong, since most IDs are listed as being non-eventful for all quarters.

**How can I produce the table "nonevent_qtrs" I described, which contains a list of quarters for which each ID had no events?**

If it's relevant, the ultimate use-case is to calculate runs of non-events to look at time-till-event analysis and prediction.  Feels like run length encoding will be required.  If there's a more direct approach than what I've described above then I'm all ears.  The only reason I'm focusing on non-event runs to begin with is to try to limit the size of the cross-product.  I've also considered producing something like:

```
| id  | last_doq   | event |
| 1   | 2010-01-31 | 1     |
| ... | ...        | ...   |
| 1   | 2018-06-30 | 0     |
| ... | ...        | ...   |
```

But although more useful this may not be feasible due to the size of the data involved.  A wide format:

```
| id  | 2010-01-31 | ... | 2018-06-30 |
| 1   | 1          | ... | 0          |
| 2   | 0          | ... | 1          |
| ... | ...        | ... | ...        |
```

would also be handy, but since MonetDB is column-store I'm not sure whether this is more or less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume that you have a table of quarters, with the start date of a quarter and the end date.  You really need this if you want the quarters that *don't* exist.  After all, how far back in time or forward in time do you want to go?

Then, you can generate all id/quarter combinations and filter out the ones that exist:

```
select i.id, q.*
from (select distinct id from events) i cross join
     quarters q left join
     events e
     on e.id = i.id and
        e.start_date <= q.quarter_end and
        e.end_date >= q.quarter_start
where e.id is null;
```

Comment: Appears to work a treat, and I see the logic of the query clearly.  Final table is about 56 million rows, so not as bad as I'd feared.